# regarding updating rows in table without using loop

Tags: sql-server

I have table in which I have column called quantity also I have 10 rows which having same column value 200(it can be any value)

Requirement is: if a input value is x=500(or anynumber) then this value should be compared with quantity column value in a fasion below:
if 1 row's quantity is 200 then it should subtract it form 500 and x should be updated to 300 and quantity of that row should be made 0 then It should move to next row till x is 0

could you please help me write sql query for this...

it is ask that loops should not be used.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of SQL Server? If it's 2012 or 2014, you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @x int = 500

;WITH cte_sum AS
(
    SELECT quantity,
       ISNULL(SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) sum_running_before,
       SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) sum_running_total
FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE cte_sum
SET quantity = CASE
                WHEN quantity >= @x - sum_running_before THEN
                     quantity - (@x - sum_running_before)
                ELSE 0
            END
WHERE (@x >= sum_running_total OR (@x < sum_running_total AND sum_running_before < @x))
```

It's a bit more tricky to get running totals in earlier versions but I think you got the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(
    CustId INT,
    Quantity INT
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable
( CustId, Quantity )
VALUES
( 1, 10 ),
( 1, 10 ),
( 1, 10 ),
( 1, 10 ),
( 2, 20 ),
( 2, 20 ),
( 2, 20 ),
( 2, 20 );

;WITH cte_sum AS
(
    SELECT 
        y.CustId,
        y.Quantity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY Quantity) RN
    FROM @YourTable y
)
SELECT s1.CustId, s1.Quantity, s2.Qty, s1.Quantity + ISNULL(s2.Qty, 0) RunningTotal, s1.RN
FROM cte_sum s1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(Quantity) Qty FROM cte_sum s2
    WHERE s2.CustId = s1.CustId
        AND s2.RN < s1.RN
) s2
ORDER BY s1.CustId, s1.RN
```

Here's an example of a running total that will work for Sql Server 2005+

This is the output:

```
CustId  Quantity    Qty RunningTotal    RN
1   10  NULL    10  1
1   10  10  20  2
1   10  20  30  3
1   10  30  40  4
2   20  NULL    20  1
2   20  20  40  2
2   20  40  60  3
2   20  60  80  4
```